Chose Gate-Source voltage based on characteristics
I don't quite understand how to choose the best gate-source voltage for this MOSFET.
The question goes like this:
Va = 24V DC and would this steplessly control the power of a heater from 0 kW to 1.0 kW. The heater has an internal resistance of Rl = 0.576 mΩ.

For this, I thought to determine the maximum drain current: P = id*V -> id = 1000/24 = 41.6A. And then based on that I would say that 5.5V should be put at the gate.
But why is that, because then surely this point is more to the right side and I would expect to static losses to be higher than just picking 20 V.

Your method is naïve and will result in the MOSFET failing in milliseconds. You need to finding a switching solution to this problem.

But this is not about the practical realization it is just about the theoretical calculations.

Theoretically and practically your method is naïve if that helps you understand what I'm saying.

I don't think 0.57mΩ is right. I think you mean 0.57Ω. That would give you a power of $P=\frac{V^2}{R}=\frac{24^2}{0.57}=1kW$, and current of $I=\frac{V}{R}=\frac{24}{0.57}=42A$
